# Matplotlib: how to exact align the title to the y label?

Tags: matplotlib

In matplotlib I can easily align the title to the left with this command:

```
ax.set_title(f"Title", ha='left', x=-0)
```

and I get:

[image: Title aligned to the left]

But sometimes I want to align the title to where the left label begins, to get something like:

[image: Title aligned to the left label]

I usually do it by trial and error. At the end I get an arbitrary x offset like:

```
ax.set_title(f"Title", ha='left', x=-.12)
```

How would I automatically calculate this `-.12` offset?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using transformations (see [Transformation tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html)), you can find the position of the left side of the label bounding box and transform that into *axes coordinates* to pass to `set_title()`:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.canvas.draw()
bbox = ax.get_yticklabels()[-1].get_window_extent()
x,_ = ax.transAxes.inverted().transform([bbox.x0, bbox.y0])
ax.set_title('A title aligned with the y-axis labels', ha='left', x=x)
```

[image]

Comment: This is a nice answer. The example works, but I'm having trouble using it. This examples does not correctly plot the title: `ax = sns.load_dataset('iris').plot.line();bbox = ax.get_yticklabels()[0].get_window_extent();x, _ = ax.transAxes.inverted().transform([bbox.x0, bbox.y0]);ax.set_title("My test", x=x, ha='left')`

Comment: weird, my figure was displayed in my notebook, but the code above just worked after including the line `fig.canvas.draw()`. I don't get it.